# EF6 generating date comparison sql for MySql database

Tags: mysql, linq, date, entity-framework-6, compare

I have a web app built in .NETCore 2.1 which calls an API built in .Net 4.6. The API calls a services layer which is using entity framework 6. I'm connecting to a MySql database. I'm using the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql connector. When using a LINQ query to get records based on a date comparison, EF6 appears to be cmparing the dates as string literals.

I've tried all different types of variations of the LINQ query and looked online for extension libraries that do date comparisons, but to no avail

Here's the LINQ query

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

                DateTime firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

                DateTime lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);



                var startDate = firstDayOfYear.AddYears(-2);

                var endDate = lastDayOfYear.AddYears(-1);



                var company = dbContext.Companies.Where(c =>

                    c.Updating &&

                    c.UpdatedBy == username &&

                    c.LastUpdate > startDate &&

                    c.LastUpdate < endDate)

                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here's part of the SQL that is generated. note the @ symbols before the date values

```
`Extent2`.`ID` AS `ID1`,

`Extent2`.`Name` AS `Name1`

FROM Company AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `Table_2` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent2`.`ID`

WHERE ((((`Extent1`.`SomeFlag` != 1) AND (`Extent1`.`LastUpdate` > @'01/01/2017 00:00:00')) AND (`Extent1`.`LastUpdate` < @'31/12/2017 00:00:00')) AND ((`Extent1`.`ID` IN ( '1','2','6','7','8' )) AND (`Extent1`.`ID` IS NOT NULL))) AND (NOT ((`Extent1`.`Telephone` IS  NULL) OR ((LENGTH(`Extent1`.`Telephone`)) = 0)))) AS `Project1`
```

Running the sql query manually in MySql workbench returns no rows. if I remove the @ symbols it does return rows, as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The SQL you've posted looks like generated by EF6, not EF Core (EF Core queries do not use `Extent` and `Project` in aliases).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Regardless, the problem still exists. Any idea how to get round the problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem to exist (at least in the latest EF Core 2.x) - `startDate` is translated to something like `@__startDate_0` (parameter).

Comment: startDate and endDate are both translated into what looks like string literals in the sql query. See the date strings prefixed with @ symbols. The query works perfectly if I run it manually without the @ symbols. Running it manually with the @ symbols, I get nothing. No error, but also on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why EF was translating the LINQ that way so I just used a stored procedure call to get round it. At least then I could write the SQL myself.

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

            DateTime firstDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

            DateTime lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);



            var startDate = firstDayOfYear.AddYears(QueueConfig.UpdateQueueStartDateInYears);

            var endDate = lastDayOfYear.AddYears(QueueConfig.UpdateQueueStartDateInYears);



            var userParam = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("userName", username);

            var sdParam = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("startDate", startDate);

            var edParam = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("endDate", endDate);

            var lockedCompany = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CompanyDto>("CALL GetLockedCompany(@userName,@startDate,@endDate)", userParam, sdParam, edParam);



            var companyDto = lockedCompany.SingleOrDefault();
```